CameraX preview page not working with navigation
So I have camera preview page that implements google mlkit's ocr option and it works if I run it as is but if I link it by navigation through a button the page opens up but the camera preview is not working.
@Composable
fun CameraPreviewScreen(

) {
    val lensFacing = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
    val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    val context = LocalContext.current
   

    val cameraController: LifecycleCameraController =
        remember { LifecycleCameraController(context) }

    val previewView = remember {
        PreviewView(context)
    }

    var detectedText: String by remember { mutableStateOf("Recognized text goes here") }

    fun onTextUpdated(updatedText: String) {
        detectedText = updatedText

    }

    
    val imageCapture = remember {
        ImageCapture.Builder().build()
    }


    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        AndroidView({
            previewView.also { previewView ->
                //function for text recognition
                    initializeTextRecognition(
                    context = context,
                    cameraController = cameraController,
                    lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner,
                    previewView = previewView,
                    onDetectedTextUpdated = ::onTextUpdated
                )
            }

        }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
        Button(onClick = { captureImage(imageCapture, context) }) {
            Text(text = "Capture Image")
        }
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.White)
                .padding(16.dp),
            color = Color.Black,
            text = detectedText,
        )
    }
}

I've read through the state documentation and I suspect that the problem lies with the lifecycleowner not being set up correctly but I'm not quite deeply knowledgeable yet to approach this problem.
